# data.table issue in R (columns specify non existing column(s))

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Hello I used this code :

```
setDT(tab)[interval_tab, V1 := scaffold,on =  .(V1, V2 >= start, V2 <= end)]
```

and I got the error :

```
Error in colnamesInt(i, unname(on), check_dups = FALSE) : 
  argument specifying columns specify non existing column(s): cols[1]='V1'
```

and yet the column `V1` does exist in the `tab` dataframe I do not understand...

---

here is an example :

Hello I have a **df1** :

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1  1   2
JZSA01000001.1  2   2
JZSA01000001.1  3   2
JZSA01000001.1  4   2
JZSA01000001.1  5   2
JZSA01000001.1  6   2
JZSA01000001.1  7   2
JZSA01000001.1  8   2
JZSA01000001.1  9   2
JZSA01000001.1  10  2
JZSA01000001.1  11  5
JZSA01000001.1  12  5
JZSA01000001.1  13  5
JZSA01000001.1  14  5
JZSA01000001.1  15  5
JZSA01000001.1  16  5
JZSA01000001.1  17  5
JZSA01000001.1  18  6
JZSA01000002.1  1   2
JZSA01000002.1  2   2
JZSA01000002.1  3   2
JZSA01000002.1  4   2
JZSA01000002.1  5   2
JZSA01000002.1  6   2
JZSA01000003.1  1   5
JZSA01000003.1  2   5
JZSA01000003.1  3   6
JZSA01000003.1  4   6
JZSA01000003.1  5   6
JZSA01000003.1  6   6
JZSA01000003.1  7   6
JZSA01000003.1  8   6
JZSA01000003.1  9   6
```

and another **df_interval**

```
scaffold          start     end
JZSA01000001.1_0  1         14
JZSA01000001.1_1  15        18
JZSA01000002.1    1         12
JZSA01000003.1_0  1         3
JZSA01000003.1_1  4         6
JZSA01000003.1_2  7         9
```

and I would like to change the `df1$scaf_name` according to the `df1$scaf_name$start` and `df1$scaf_name$end`

so for instance

every `df1$scaf_name` containing `df_interval$scaffold`  and where `df1$coordinates` os between `1-14` would be named `JZSA01000001.1_0`

Here I should get as output

```
scaf_name       coordinates value    
JZSA01000001.1_0    1   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    2   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    3   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    4   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    5   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    6   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    7   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    8   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    9   2
JZSA01000001.1_0    10  2
JZSA01000001.1_0    11  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    12  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    13  5
JZSA01000001.1_0    14  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    15  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    16  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    17  5
JZSA01000001.1_1    18  6
JZSA01000002.1      1   2
JZSA01000002.1      2   2
JZSA01000002.1      3   2
JZSA01000002.1      4   2
JZSA01000002.1      5   2
JZSA01000002.1      6   2
JZSA01000003.1_0    1   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    2   5
JZSA01000003.1_0    3   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    4   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    5   6
JZSA01000003.1_1    6   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    7   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    8   6
JZSA01000003.1_2    9   6
```

The df1 file is very huge, if someone have and idea to be the fastest possible it would be amazing.
Thank you

DATA

**df1**

```
structure(list(scaf_name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1", 
"JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1"), class = "factor"), coor = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), dinates.value = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-33L))
```

**df_interval**

```
structure(list(scaffold = structure(1:6, .Label = c("JZSA01000001.1_0", 
"JZSA01000001.1_1", "JZSA01000002.1", "JZSA01000003.1_0", "JZSA01000003.1_1", 
"JZSA01000003.1_2"), class = "factor"), start = c(1L, 15L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 7L), end = c(14L, 18L, 12L, 3L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: You are using `V1' as a  joining column.  Can you show an example

Comment: @akrun yes sure I edited the post by adding exemple

Comment: Based on your new example, I used `setDT(df1)[df_interval, V1 := scaffold,on =  .(scaf_name = scaffold, coor >= start, coor <= end)]` didn't show any error